# Sentence generator

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++ and I'm doing a little project where I have to generate a sentence by using strings from array. The problem is that sometimes a string from the same array is ran twice even though the calculation moves from one array to the next, or sometimes the array is completely skipped. here are some examples the code prints:

```
some cat ran drove the shop. //here the verb[] array is ran twice
some girl town on a boy. //here the nounPerson[] array is run but immediately the nounPlace[] array is ran next, instead of verb[] array like I tried to do in the code
the the ran over the boy //here the same thing happens, the first word is printed twice and the nounPerson[] is skipped
```

Maybe my understanding of arrays is wrong, or maybe it's the random number generator. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string article[5] = {"the ", "a ", "one ", "some ", "my "};
    string nounPerson[5] = {"boy ", "girl ", "dog ", "cat ", "person "};
    string nounPlace[5] = {"town ", "cafe ", "shop ", "store ", "house "};
    string verb[5] = {"drove ", "jumped ", "ran ", "walked ", "striked "};
    string preposition[5] = {"to ", "from ", "over ", "across ", "on "};
    string sentence;
    int word, word1, word2, word3, word4, word5;

    srand(time(0));

    word = rand() % 6;
    word1 = rand() % 6;
    word2 = rand() % 6;
    word3 = rand() % 6;
    word4 = rand() % 6;
    word5 = rand() % 6;

    //this is where the strings from the arrays add up to make a sentence
    sentence = article[word];
    sentence = sentence + nounPerson[word1];
    sentence = sentence + verb[word2];
    sentence = sentence + preposition[word3];
    sentence = sentence + article[word4];
    sentence = sentence + nounPlace[word5];

    cout << sentence << endl;
}
```

Also sometimes I get std::bad_alloc error and I have no idea what that is/how to fix that

Comment: you need to divide by 5 not by 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand() % 6` will generate a value between `0` and `5`, both inclusive. Of those, all values are valid indices for you arrays except `5`. When you get `5`, you access your arrays using an out of bounds index, which results in undefined behavior.

Use `rand() % 5` instead.

```
word = rand() % 5;
word1 = rand() % 5;
word2 = rand() % 5;
word3 = rand() % 5;
word4 = rand() % 5;
word5 = rand() % 5;
```

I would have used `index` instead of `word` since they are indices to the arrays.

```
index1 = rand() % 5;
index2 = rand() % 5;
index3 = rand() % 5;
index4 = rand() % 5;
index5 = rand() % 5;
index6 = rand() % 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very small correction in your Code:

```
  srand(time(0));
  word = rand() % 5;
  word1 = rand() % 5;
  word2 = rand() % 5;
  word3 = rand() % 5;
  word4 = rand() % 5;
  word5 = rand() % 5;
```

Since the index of an array starts from 0, therefore array of size 5 starts from 0 and ends on 4.
And you are generating the number between 0 to 5 (both inclusive) in your rand() function. So just change it from 6 to 5 to generate it 0 to 4 (both inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays placed on the stack one after another. Every one of them of length 5, so maximum allowed index is 4. But you divide by 6 - `% 6`, you just need to divide by 5.

Instead c-arrays, you can use `std::array` and use `at` to access elements with checking:

```
const int size = 5;
array<string,size> article = { "the ", "a ", "one ", "some ", "my " };
array<string, size> nounPerson = { "boy ", "girl ", "dog ", "cat ", "person " };
array<string, size> nounPlace = { "town ", "cafe ", "shop ", "store ", "house " };
array<string, size> verb = { "drove ", "jumped ", "ran ", "walked ", "striked " };
array<string, size> preposition = { "to ", "from ", "over ", "across ", "on " };
string sentence;
int word, word1, word2, word3, word4, word5;

srand(time(0));
// the best is to divide by array size,
// in case of c-arrays it would be % (sizeof(article)/sizeof(string))
word = rand() % article.size();
word1 = rand() % nounPerson.size();
word2 = rand() % verb.size();
word3 = rand() % preposition.size();
word4 = rand() % article.size();
word5 = rand() % nounPlace.size();
//this is where the strings from the arrays add up to make a sentence
sentence = article[word];
sentence = sentence + nounPerson.at(word1);
sentence = sentence + verb.at(word2);
sentence = sentence + preposition.at(word3);
sentence = sentence + article.at(word4);
sentence = sentence + nounPlace.at(word5);

cout << sentence << endl;
```